# Power BI DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from url error?

Tags: powerbi

Recently my Power BI dashboard has started to return an error and I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain why it might have failed?

The error I'm getting is:

[image: DataSource Error]

The Advanced Query I'm using is:

```
let
    url = "http://<domain>:<port>/jderest/orchestrator/SEF_ORCH_V4211APBISalesDash",
    body = "{""deviceName"":""PowerBI"",""username"":""<username>"",""password"":""<password>""}",
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[ContentType="application/json"],Content = Text.ToBinary(body)]))
in
    Source
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with it. I tried running it via Soup UI with the above and it worked.

[image]

Can anyone explain why the Advanced Query is erroring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the solution. It looks like it stemmed from a newer update.

What was wrong is `ContentType="application/json"` in the headers needed to have it's format updated. The correct format is `#"Content-Type"="application/json"`.

So the original code:

```
let
    url = "http://<domain>:<port>/jderest/orchestrator/SEF_ORCH_V4211APBISalesDash",
    body = "{""deviceName"":""PowerBI"",""username"":""<username>"",""password"":""<password>""}",
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[ContentType="application/json"],Content = Text.ToBinary(body)]))
in
    Source
```

Needed to be:

```
let
    url = "http://<domain>:<port>/jderest/orchestrator/SEF_ORCH_V4211APBISalesDash",
    body = "{""deviceName"":""PowerBI"",""username"":""<username>"",""password"":""<password>""}",
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json"],Content = Text.ToBinary(body)]))
in
    Source
```

The reason for this is because after an update (not sure which one) `ContentType="application/json"` was treated as a miscellaneous tag

[image]

With the change to `#"Content-Type"="application/json"` It was no longer a miscellaneous tag. It is treated as an entity like before.

[image]